# Difference in regex behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, yup

I am trying to build a regex to match a field which should contain exactly 9 digits

I use the below regex

```
/^\d{9,9}$/
```

Now, the issue is while doing

```
/^\d{9,9}$/.test("123456789") //returns true
```

But, when I try to use the same exact regex (passed in myRegex below) using Yup's matches

```
'myField': yup
            .string()
            .nullable()
            .required('Field is required')
            .max(9, `Max length 9`)
            .matches(myRegex, {
                message: 'Field is invalid',
            }),
```

I get invalid message for the same input i.e. 123456789

Just wondering why that is the case ?

**Update:**
Yup uses value.search(regex) and so, in my case, it runs "123456789".search(/^\d{9,9}$/)

Not sure if above is the issue ?

Comment: If you want a string with exactly 9 digits, wouldn't this expression be more correct `/^\d{9,9}$/`?

Comment: 9-digits as max is indicated in Yup. It could be less than 9 but can't go more than 9. However, the first sentence said "contain exactly 9 digits" so we need clarification from OP if it's max 9 or exactly 9.

Comment: yeah, it should be exactly 9 digits

Comment: @NNL993 : Updating the regex to /^\d{9,9}$/ also passed via .test(), but fails via Yup's matches

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a string?

Comment: Yes...it is a string...I added a breakpoint as well....it is via the value user enters in an input textbox

Comment: On further debugging in Yup library code, I see it uses value.search(regex) and so, in my case, it runs "123456789".search(/^\d{9,9}$/) returns -1

Comment: So looks like some issue here ? Please suggest

Comment: Is there any alternative to using the matches in Yup ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using wrong regex for your solution

The problem arises when Yup's search() method is used with the regular expression. The search() method returns the index of the first match, and it does not evaluate the full string.

Since "123456789" contains 9 digits consecutively, the regular expression is satisfied, and the search() method returns the index of the first occurrence, which is 0. Since 0 is a truthy value, Yup interprets it as a failed match and returns the invalid message.

Here is the regex you can try with `/^\d{9}$/`

Comment: Thanks....Even with the new regex you have given, value.search(regex) gives -1

Comment: Also I assume you meant 0 is a falsy value and not "truthy" ?

Comment: Yes, 0 == false, if you can share your code with fiddle or someone platform i can help you to get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks...But this regex is what worked for me /^[0-9]+$/

But I am wondering because of Yup's value.search(regex), will I have to alter my way of defining regexes...as I will have many more regexes